# pandas agg with mode produces "ValueError: cannot combine transform and aggregation operations"

Tags: pandas, aggregate-functions, mode

I am trying to apply multiple aggregate functions to the columns of a dataframe.

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,1,2,2,2],[3,3,4,4,5]]).T,columns=['A','B'])
df_test
```

```
    A   B
0   1   3
1   1   3
2   2   4
3   2   4
4   2   5
```

As we see below, 'min', 'max', 'mean', and 'median' are all working fine:

```
df_test.agg(['min','max','mean','median'])
```

```
        A   B
min     1.0 3.0
max     2.0 5.0
mean    1.6 3.8
median  2.0 4.0
```

When I add the 'mode' to the list of "agg" functions, things get messy:

```
df_test.agg(['min','max','mean','median','mode'])
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in agg_list_like(self)
    381         try:
--> 382             concatenated = concat(results, keys=keys, axis=1, sort=False)
    383         except TypeError as err:

11 frames
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in agg_list_like(self)
    390                 raise ValueError(
    391                     "cannot combine transform and aggregation operations"
--> 392                 ) from err
    393             return result
    394         else:

ValueError: cannot combine transform and aggregation operations
```

Which is probably is due to fact that "mode" produces more than one value for each column, as in my case:

```
df_test.agg('mode')
```

```
    A   B
0   2.0 3
1   NaN 4
```

However, even if I try with a different test dataframe, where is only a single mode value for each column:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,1,2,2,2],[3,3,3,4,4]]).T,columns=['A','B'])
display(df_test)
df_test.agg('mode')
```

```
    A   B
0   1   3
1   1   3
2   2   3
3   2   4
4   2   4

    A   B
0   2   3
```

```
df_test.agg(['min','max','mean','median','mode'])
```

on this new test dataframe still produces the same error message that I've copied above.. I guess this issue can be addressed using "apply" and some "suitable" lambda function :). However, I really would like to know how we can still use this practical "agg" function in this situation. Thanks..

I've also tried using "mode()[0]" as suggested in other posts, still no luck:

```
df_test.agg(['min','max','mean','median',mode()[0]])
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-3cf938be7497> in <module>
----> 1 df_test.agg(['min','max','mean','median',mode()[0]])

NameError: name 'mode' is not defined
```

Comment: there can be multiple modes, so you cannot use it with `min`/`max`/`mean`/etc. you must use a custom function that returns a single value

Comment: You need to use a function like `lambda x: mode(x)[0]`. Preferably a named function so you get a well-named column

Comment: upon #mozway s and #creanion s suggestions, I've made the following change and everything works fine now. :)

def my_mode_fun(x):
  return x.mode()[0]

df_test.agg(['min','max','mean','median',my_mode_fun])

Thanks a lot for your comments..